# Binding model property to radio buttons

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to bind my model property to the following code

```
<td>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-default active">
                <input type="radio" name="option" id="YesOption" value="Yes"> Yes
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="option" id="NoOption" value="No"/> No
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

My model property is. Model.GetEmailNotification which is either 'Yes' or 'No'

How do I bind the radio buttons? Thanks.

I changed my View code to the following and change the model.GetEmailNotification to false, but I do not see the No button on the View being selected. Any help is appreciated.

```
<td>
                            <div class="col-xs-7">
                                <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => @Model.GetEmailNotification , true) Yes

                                    </label>
                                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => @Model.GetEmailNotification , false) No

                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
```

In my ViewModel,

public bool GetEmailNotification { get; set; }

I am not sure why the button is not selected.

Comment: `@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.GetEmailNotification, "Yes")` an a second one with `"No"` But the property name suggests it should be `bool`, not `string` (it which case the values would be `"True"` and `"False"`)

Comment: Based on your edit, what is typeof `GetEmailNotification`?

Comment: `@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.GetEmailNotification, true)` and `@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.GetEmailNotification, false)` will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `@` sign inside the expression:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => Model.GetEmailNotification, true) Yes
```